# Choosing a suitable PHP framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, symfony, frameworks

I have a problem, I have two weeks to learn about frameworks and MVC. I have learned MVC, but I didn't understand either of the Symfony or Zend frameworks; usually i do my projects with ?post=id.

I think I should learn how frameworks work, since they are more professional and offer more security. I need a way to learn frameworks, and which one should I choose?

Comment: How is your question related to your database schema?

Comment: to show you how small\big this project to use frameworks or not !!

Comment: I've removed your db schema from the question, since it didn't seem to be relevant to the question. I think this question will be closed, since comparative questions tend to be regarded as subjective, hence off-topic. If you look in the _Related_ sidebar, there's plenty of questions like this.

Comment: We can't tell from the question how much experience you have, or how long you've been a programmer. However if you are a beginner, then it is a good idea not to "bite off more than you can chew" - being over-optimistic about ones abilities where a tight deadline is imposed can cost you (or someone else) time and money, so please be careful!

Comment: thanks, this my website: art3ataby.com, my experience not good enough but i'm really trying hard to be a good programmer, thanks again for this point Halfer

Comment: @Michaelroshdy: Keep working on your skills and slowly but surely you will become a good programmer. I am sure every single person here at SO keeps continuously working on theirs too.. All the best, Michael!

Comment: For anyone wondering which framework to choose, read and watch Uncle Bob: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18853233/1614973

Answer (score 4):

First of all a framework doesn't provide more security or professionally - you can make mistakes just as much as you can when developing from scratch.

Are you forced to learn MVC and use a framework? Don't get me wrong but if you are on a tough deadline I would prefer to stick to what you know as you can run into many problems with frameworks when you are not familier with them or the pattern.

As also the best way to get a quick overview is using google - here is my first search result wich looks pretty good.

http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/05/24/an-overview-of-php-framework-guides-for-developers/

Comment: really thank you Tim, i will try this link and hope you recommend me Code Igniter too !

Comment: my current favorite is cakephp but CodeIgniter is a solid well supported framework. It doesn't really matter wich one is used as a starting point as long as they offer a good documentation

Answer (score 0):

If you are now good with `MVC` but want to learn `MVC Framework Architecture`, then you should try `Code Igniter`. That is powerful, lightweight framework and even it is too much easy and simple to understand.

You can even try `Kohana` for this.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks, i will try this one, but is it have a good documentation or :( !!

Comment: Yeah. Code Igniter have extensive documentation that will help you to learn easily. Kohana don't have too much documentation or examples. So, if you want to use Kohana, you need to read the core, and probably you can't do that right now. So, jump to CI. Mark Tick if this works. Thanks